# unable to import MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, database-connection

I have created a website that uses a `MySQL` database, but when i put it online, it doesn't work anymore. in my class `connection.vb` that i use for my connection to my database i get the following warning:

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' doesn't contain any   public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains   at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

and it says that the type `mysqlconnection` is not defined.

this is my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class connection
    Public Shared cn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnDatabase").ConnectionString)
End Class
```

If i do the same imports statement in an other `vb` file such as e.g index.aspx.vb it gives me no error

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Double click in My Project.
2. In the tab "References" remove    MySQL.Data.
3. Try to re-install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to embed the `dll` files for `Mysql`. Check the dependencies of your project, resources paths must be different from your local configuration.
I think you can find what you're looking for on this [website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads)

Comment: This looks like a comment, can you please further elaborate your answer?

Comment: my dll files are located in my bin folder, so i think that's not the problem

Comment: On which platform did you put your webiste ? I had the problem once with Windows server 2008. Indeed the dll files were in the bin folder but it seems that putting them in the system32 windows' folder also help me out this time.

Comment: I have outsourced the publishing so i dont really know what they use, but think they say they use Windows server 2008

Answer (score 0):

try this,
You have to remove old reference of that file add new reference as when we are copying file from one machine to another machine the reference for assembly is some time also taking from copied machine.

so you can check this,

1. Select ->Properties of project
2. Go to the reference
   3.check the reference of assembly exists or not
3. if path showing "The system cannot find the reference specified"
4. download latest MySql connector/Net from     https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ for .Net Mono
5. remove the reference and add the new reference from visual studio-Proerties-reference